# Is it possible to flash tags with flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I know that if I put

```
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

the tags will work, but I want to flash html tags on demand, which changes depending on which function sent it. Therefore, I tried this:

```
   def loginSubmit():
     flash("<p>Username is not correct.</p>","info")
     return redirect("/login")
```

However, although the rest of the page worked as expected, it printed the tags as text instead of reading them as html.

This is the relevant part of the html file:

```
 <html>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% for message in messages%}
             {{message}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
  </html>
```

Is there a way to flash tags? Why do flashed messages only work as text and not html?

Comment: "Why do flashed messages only work as text and not html?" because that's the way `flash` was implemented. :-)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29807235/12851576